# Return a modified version of same type in F#

Tags: f#

If I've got a class hierarchy like

```
type Employee(name) =
  member val name: string = name

type HourlyEmployee(name, rate) =
  inherit Employee(name)
  member val rate: int = rate

type SalariedEmployee(name, salary) =
  inherit Employee(salary)
  member val salary: int = salary
```

And I want a function that updates the `name` field in a pure way, how is this possible?  A couple failed options:

```
let changeName(employee: Employee) = 
  // no idea what class this was, so this can only return the base class

let changeName<'a when 'a :> Employee>(employee: 'a) =
  // 'a has no constructor
```

The closest thing I've come up with is making a virtual `Employee.changeName` and implementing that on each class.  That just seems like a lot of extra work *plus* it's error-prone since the return type is `Employee` and has to be upcasted back to the original class.

Seems like there should be a simpler, safer way to do such a task.  Is this something where typeclasses are necessary?

## Update

Yes I could just make the `name` field mutable, which is how it is implemented in my code now, but that's what I'm wanting to get away from.

## Update 2

A solution I've come up with, that meets type safety and conciseness requirements, would be to define

```
type Employee<'a> = {name: string; otherStuff: 'a}
```

and then just use `with` syntax to change the name.  But `otherStuff: 'a` is obviously ugly and hacky looking code, so I'm still open to better solutions.

Comment: if you intend to make your property writable why not "simply" make the [property writable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483467.aspx) ? `member val name = name with get, set`

Comment: @Sehnsucht I should have mentioned, that's how I'm doing it now, but wanting to go toward a more pure implementation of things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking for something both pure and **idiomatic F#**, then you shouldn't be using an inheritance hierarchy in the first place. That's an object-oriented concept.

In F#, you could model Employee like this, using algebraic data types:

```
type HourlyData = { Name : string; Rate : int }
type SalaryData = { Name : string; Salary : int }

type Employee =
| Hourly of HourlyData
| Salaried of SalaryData
```

This would enable you to create `Employee` values like this:

```
> let he = Hourly { Name = "Bob"; Rate = 100 };;

val he : Employee = Hourly {Name = "Bob";
                            Rate = 100;}

> let se = Salaried { Name = "Jane"; Salary = 10000 };;

val se : Employee = Salaried {Name = "Jane";
                              Salary = 10000;}
```

You can also define a function to change the name in a pure manner:

```
let changeName newName = function
    | Hourly h -> Hourly { h with Name = newName }
    | Salaried s -> Salaried { s with Name = newName }
```

This enables you to change the name of an existing `Employee` value like this:

```
> let se' = se |> changeName "Mary";;

val se' : Employee = Salaried {Name = "Mary";
                               Salary = 10000;}
```

Comment: Still a little more verbose than I want; for a large number of cases you'd have to repeat `| Blah b -> Blah { b with Name = newName` for each case.  I think I'll use the idea though, but limit it to a subfield of an `Employee` record.  So, `type Employee = {name: string, payData: PayData}`, where `PayData` is an ADT.